# Multiple screens support for slideshows

Tags: slideshows

I really like using Mathematica for building slideshows/presentations.

But is mirroring the only way to see the content both on the laptop's screen and on the projector?

When using screen mirroring, the projector display is blurry because the resolution doesn't match.
When not using screen mirroring, having to constantly switch back and forth between the screen, the audience and the keyboard is really not convenient.

Is there a better way to use Mathematica on multiple screens?